# How to change the below to date format

Tags: r, posix, as.date

Tried below queries

```
data <- data.frame(initialDiagnose = c("2/9/2018 0:07"))
dmy_data <- dmy_hms(data$initialDiagnose)
```

Output :

```
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

I have values similar to this in multiple formats like `ymd`, `dmy` so could not use `as.posixct` directly. please suggest

Comment: You need `dmy_hm(c("2/9/2018 0:07"))` not `dmy_hms`

Comment: Please indicate which package the `dmy_hms` function is from

Comment: it worked. Thankyou

Comment: its from Lubridate package

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you would definitely need `dmy_hm` instead of `dmy_hms`

```
dmy_hm(c("2/9/2018 0:07"))
```